# Problem reading Json response . "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json, array.prototype.map

Hi' I'm getting  data from a  Json service  with data with FETCH function in reactJs. when I obtain the array save the answer in a variable:

```
      const resp = await fetch(url);   
      const { contenidos = [] } = await resp.json();
```

The Json is ( have 500 items):

```
[
    {
        "custom_fields": {
            "v2_titulo": {
                "id": 1561385,
                "value": "Algun titulo acá"
            },
            "v2_extracto": {
                "id": 1561386,
                "value": "extracto de la noticia acá"
            },
            "v2_descripcion": {
                "id": 1561387,
                "value": "descripción de la noticia acá"
            },
            "v2_vigencia": {
                "id": 1561388,
                "value": "Vigencia"
            }            
        },
        "id": 12388,
        "uuid": "7fb8560c-7a18-481f-abfa-a0e331255f81",
        "created_at": "2023-07-21T09:33:32.000-04:00",
        "updated_at": "2023-07-21T09:33:32.000-04:00",
        "published_at": "2024-01-15T10:13:33.000-03:00",
        "covers": [
            "https://noticias/covernoticia.jpg",
            "https://noticias/logonoticia.jpg"
        ],
        "tags": [
            "actualidad",
            "providencia",
            "santiago"
        ],
        "category": "salud",
        "site_id": 1,
        "video_url": ""
    },
    {
        "custom_fields": {
            "v2_titulo": {
                "id": 1561385,
                "value": "Algun titulo acá 2"
            },
            "v2_extracto": {
                "id": 1561386,
                "value": "extracto de la noticia acá 2"
            },
            "v2_descripcion": {
                "id": 1561387,
                "value": "descripción de la noticia acá 2"
            },
            "v2_vigencia": {
                "id": 1561388,
                "value": "Vigencia 2"
            }            
        },
        "id": 12388,
        "uuid": "7fb8560c-7a18-481f-abfa-a0e331255f81",
        "created_at": "2023-07-21T09:33:32.000-04:00",
        "updated_at": "2023-07-21T09:33:32.000-04:00",
        "published_at": "2024-01-15T10:13:33.000-03:00",
        "covers": [
            "https://noticias/covernoticia.jpg",
            "https://noticias/logonoticia.jpg"
        ],
        "tags": [
            "actualidad",
            "huechuraba",
            "santiago"
        ],
        "category": "salud",
        "site_id": 1,
        "video_url": ""
    }
   
]
```

I'm mapping like this:

```
  const noticias =  contenidos.map( item => ({
        id: item.id,
        banner: item.covers[0],
        logo: item.covers[1],
        title: item.custom_fields.v2_titulo.value,
        category: item.category,
       
      }));
```

it's works with id, covers, and category, but when I tried to enter "v2_titulo.value" it's doesn't work and throws :

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
> at getBCHNews.js?t=1705328829877:17:45
> at Array.map ()
> at getBCHNews (getBCHNews.js?t=1705328829877:12:36)
> at async getNews (useFetchNews.js?t=1705328829877:10:29)

can you help me please!

I need to reed v2_titulo.Value

Comment: What do you see if you just log each `item`?

Comment: [Works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/x8u1avq5/).  Is the actual data perhaps different from what you're showing here?  Can you update the question to a [mcve] as a [runnable code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/328193) which demonstrates the problem?  If you have array elements which *don't have* that property, what do you want to do with them?  What have you tried to do with them?

Comment: I'd guess that for some items in your JSON, the mentioned field `v2_titulo` is either `null` or `undefined` - especially since it belongs to the "custom fields". This means you need to safeguard access to it, for example with optional chaining (= `?.`)

Comment: Sounds like not all the items in the array have a `v2_titulo` property.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe in the response, some of the result has no 'v2_titulo' in it. So when you are trying to access 'v2_titulo' which is (undefined)  you are getting error. In that case you can use 'Optional chaining (?)' while while accessing the 'v2_titulo' value. If the 'v2_titulo' is somehow missing or (undefined) it will ignore it.

```js
  const noticias =  contenidos.map( item => ({
        id: item.id,
        banner: item.covers[0],
        logo: item.covers[1],
        title: item.custom_fields.v2_titulo?.value,
        category: item.category,
       
      }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, your code worked for me without issue. I'm assuming it's similar to what [Davi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9870107/davi) is saying in that some of the titles are `null` or missing. Another way you can write the map to set the title to indicate that no title was found when it encounters a `null` or `undefined` value for `v2_titulo`, like so:

```
  const noticias =  contenidos.map( item => ({
    id: item.id,
    banner: item.covers[0],
    logo: item.covers[1],
    title: item.custom_fields.v2_titulo.value ? item.custom_fields.v2_titulo.value : "No title found" // or some other value that makes sense to you like `null`,
    category: item.category,
  }));
```